# Django- Print data in html (in app2) from model (in app1)

Tags: html, django, database, django-models, import

I have a model defined in an app.
Then I would like to see *ElementiTab* into a html of a different app.

**models.py APP1 (named simpleapp)**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from simpleapp.oper import add_divide
from django.conf import settings



class ElementiTab(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=False)
    des = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    res = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.res = add_divide(self.x, self.y)
        super(ElementiTab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.des
```

**prova.html  APP2**
Something like

```
{% for elementi in elementimenu %}
    <div class="elementi">
        <tr>
            <td>{{elementi.des}}</td> 
            <td>{{elementi.x}}</td>
            <td>{{elementi.y}}</td>
            <td>{{elementi.res}}</td>
            <td>{{elementi.created_date}}</td>
            <td>{{elementi.author}}</td>
        </tr>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

A) **views.py APP2**

```
from simpleapp.models import ElementiTab    
def show_elementi(request):
        elementimenu = get_object_or_404(ElementiTab)
        return render_to_response('homepage/prova.html',{'elementimenu': elementimenu})
```

gives me *MultipleObjectsReturned at /homepage/prova/ -
get() returned more than one ElementiTab -- it returned 3!* (in this moment in my db there are 3 rows)

If I write:
B) **views.py APP2**

```
from simpleapp.models import ElementiTab 
#from ....   
def show_elementi(request,id):
        elementimenu = get_object_or_404(ElementiTab,pk=id)
        return render_to_response('homepage/prova.html',{'elementimenu': elementimenu})
```

It returns *TypeError at /homepage/prova/ - show_elementi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'*

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am disappointed for the down vote because I am new in django and maybe to someone this may seem like a silly question but *maybe* it is important for beginners...

Comment: If it can be useful, I performed in this way:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036331/django-can-double-render-to-response-be-unified-into-only-one-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `get_object_or_404()` shortcut:

```
def show_elementi(request):
    elementimenu = ElementiTab.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('homepage/prova.html',
                              {'elementimenu': elementimenu})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I tried with different ways but I thought it was necessary to call in some way the objects with their id, like I did earlier in order to delete the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` can retrieve only one object. If there are more than one element matching, it will throw exception.

To retrieve more than one element, you can use:

```
elementimenu = ElementiTab.objects.all()
```

If you want to return 404 when there are no objects:

```
from django.http import Http404
# ...
def show_elementi(request, id):
    elementimenu = ElementiTab.objects.all()
    if not elementimenu:
        throw Http404()
    # ...
```

Comment: with 'id' it gives Error. It works with @catavaran solution without id. But thanks for the explanation about get_object_or_404!