# Django: can "double" 'render_to_response' be unified into only one view?

Tags: html, django, url, view, render-to-response

I have defined two functions in *views.py* to obtain first prova.html with certain *elementimenu* and then, after clicking over one of them, I obtain again the page with *elementimenu* and *elementi* associated to *elementimenu* with the same id i.e.:

**another_app.model.py**

```
...
class ElementiTab(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=False)
    des = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    res = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
...
```

And here the code that I like to get better:

**views.py**

```
from another_app.model import ElementiTab

def show_elementi(request):
        elementimenu = ElementiTab.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('homepage/prova.html',{'elementimenu': elementimenu, 'user.username': request}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))


def show_detail(request,id):
        elementimenu = ElementiTab.objects.all()
        detail = get_object_or_404(ElementiTab, pk=id)
        return render_to_response('homepage/prova.html',{'elementimenu': elementimenu, 'detail': detail, 'user.username': request}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
...
      url(r'^homepage/prova/$', views.show_elementi),
      url(r'^show_detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.show_detail),
...
```

**prova.html**

```
...

    <div class="elementi">
    {% for elementi in elementimenu %}  
    <a href="/show_detail/{{elementi.id}}">{{elementi.des}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>


                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr class="info">
                                <td width="35%" align="center"> NOME</td>
                                <td width="35%" align="center"> DATA CREAZIONE </td>
                                <td width="30%" align="center"> AUTORE </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% if detail %}
                                    <div class="dettagli">
                                        <tr>

                                        <td>{{detail.des}}</td> 
                                        <td>{{detail.created_date}}</td>
                                        <td>{{detail.author}}</td>                          
                                        </tr>
                                {% endif %}  

                                    </div>

                            </table>
                        </div>
    ...
```

I had used this "trick" in *show_detail* view so that I can see *elementimenu* even after calling this function.

**Is there a more elegant way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the single view.  Add the default `None` value for the `id` (or `pk`) argument:

```
def show_elementi(request, pk=None):
    elementimenu = ElementiTab.objects.all()
    detail = get_object_or_404(ElementiTab, pk=pk) if pk else None
    return render(request, 'homepage/prova.html',
                  {'elementimenu': elementimenu, 'detail': detail})
```

And then map both urls to this view:

```
url(r'^homepage/prova/$', views.show_elementi),
url(r'^show_detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.show_elementi),
```

Comment: In this way it is more elegant, thanks! But I had to put render_to_response to avoid an *Attribute Error* ( str object has not attribute'META' ). I read the django docs but it is not very clear for me the differences between render and render_to_response.

Comment: Sorry, you should add the `request` as the first argument of the `render()`.  This is the shortcut to the `render_to_response(..., context_instance=...)`.  I updated the answer.